# Override commit Date and Time in Javers

Tags: javers

We are evaluating to use Javers for which we  will be  migrating audit data in to Javers  from git .But we want keep the same commit Date and Time as it was in git , can we override commit data time and use the same date as earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use `JaversBuilder.withDateTimeProvider​(DateProvider dateProvider)`.  [The Javadoc says](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.javers/javers-core/latest/org/javers/core/JaversBuilder.html):

> DateProvider providers current timestamp for Commit.getCommitDate(). By default, now() is used.

Comment: Many thanks @Paul  , will try and let you know the outcome

Comment: i have implemented this scenrio but its giving " ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded" i have created a seperate thread  for this issue . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73446825/maximum-open-cursors-in-javers-oracle